# Sencha touch 2 add data to nested lists

Tags: list, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have a view with nested lists and I am wondering how to add my data into the nested lists.

```
Ext.define('app.view.myview', {
extend: 'Ext.Panel',


config: {
    layout: 'vbox',
    fullscreen: true,
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'horizontallistview',
            id: 'oldotheruserhorizontallistview',
            data: **this.data.otheruser.cards**,
            flex: 1,
        },
        {
            xtype: 'horizontallistview',
            data: **this.data.thisuser.cards**,
            flex: 1,
        }
    ],


}});
```

My store looks like this:

```
data: [
        {
            id : 20001,
            thisuser: {
                cards: [
                    {
                        typeid: 5,
                        quantity:12,
                    },
                    {
                        typeid: 5,
                        quantity:12,
                    },
                    {
                        typeid: 5,
                        quantity:12,
                    },
                ]
            },
            otheruser: {
                cards: [
                    {
                        typeid: 5,
                        quantity:12,
                    },
                    {
                        typeid: 5,
                        quantity:12,
                    },
                    {
                        typeid: 5,
                        quantity:12,
                    },
                ]
            },
        },]
```

How does it work?
Like I have now "data.this.data.otheruser.cards" does not work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6414589/sencha-touch-in-need-of-a-nested-list-example

Comment: Live preview : http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.dataview.NestedList